# How to draw a layered scatterplot in R?

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I'm learning R, and want to draw a scatterplot of a large dataframe (~55000 rows). I'm using the `scatterplot` in `car`:

```
library(car) 
d=read.csv("patches.csv", header=T)
scatterplot(energy ~ homogenity | label, data=d, 
    ylab="energy", xlab="homogenity ", 
    main="Scatter Plot", 
    labels=row.names(d))
```

where `patches.csv` contains the dataframe (below)

I want to show the two `label` sets differently. With a large volume of data, the plot is very dense, so I get the result below right (mostly red data visible). The image takes a while to render, so I can see the black labelled data fleetingly (below left) before it gets hidden in the final diagram.

[image: Figure]

Can I control R to plot the data with red first, or is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Here's a sample of my data:

```
label,channel,x,y,contrast,energy,entropy,homogenity
1,21,460,76,0.991667,0.640399,0.421422,0.939831
1,22,460,76,0.0833333,0.62375,0.364379,0.969445
1,23,460,76,0.129167,0.422908,0.589938,0.935417
1,24,460,76,0,1,0,1
1,25,460,76,0,1,0,1
1,26,460,76,0.0875,0.789627,0.253649,0.967361
1,27,460,76,2.4,0.528516,0.700859,0.845558
1,28,460,76,0.120833,0.562066,0.392998,0.945139
1,29,460,76,0.0125,0.975234,0.0329461,0.99375
1,30,460,76,0,1,0,1
1,31,460,76,0.1625,0.384662,0.5859,0.929861
0,0,483,82,0.404167,0.309505,0.61573,0.947222
0,1,483,82,0.0166667,0.728559,0.221967,0.991667
0,2,483,82,0,1,0,1
0,3,483,82,0.416667,0.327083,0.644057,0.940972
0,4,483,82,0.0208333,0.919054,0.0940364,0.989583
0,5,483,82,0.416667,0.327083,0.644057,0.940972
0,6,483,82,0,1,0,1
0,7,483,82,0.0333333,0.794479,0.192471,0.983333
0,8,483,82,0,1,0,1
0,9,483,82,0,1,0,1
0,10,483,82,0.0208333,0.958984,0.0502502,0.989583
```

Comment: Have you tried semi-transparent colors? It's one common approach to _overplotting_: I think the parameter for `car::scatterplot` is `col=adjustcolor(palette()[1:2], .5)`.

Comment: Try using `ggplot`, look into `geom_point(..., alpha=0.3)`, maybe `facet_grid()`, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the order of the coloring, pass the parameter `col=2:1` to `scatterplot`, then you would be plotting red before black.  You can use the function `alpha` from `scales` package to make your points translucent (it takes a vector of colors and alpha values allowing to make each color different density).

```
## More data
d <- data.frame(homogeneity=(x=rnorm(10000, 0.85, sd=0.15)),
                label=factor((lab=1:2)),
                energy=rnorm(10000, lab^1.8*x^2-lab, sd=x))

library(car)
library(scales)         # for alpha
opacity <- c(0.3, 0.1)  # opacity for each color
col <- 1:2              # black then red
scatterplot(energy ~ homogeneity | label, data=d, 
            ylab="energy", xlab="homogenity ", 
            main=paste0(palette()[col], "(", opacity, ")", collapse=","),
            col=alpha(col, opacity),
            labels=row.names(d))
```

[image]

Comment: I want to plot the data in a different order, so sparse data is plotted over dense. The colour itself doesn't matter at this point

Comment: @cdmh you just need to change the `col` variable, for example `col=2:1` should plot the red first, then black on top.  See above.  You just want the color corresponding to the sparse data to be last in the `col` vector.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what bunk said with alpha,

If you have lots of points, the actual identification of individual points is no longer meaningful. Instead, you probably want a representation of the density. For that use `smoothScatter(x,y)` and overlay highlighted points with the usual `points(morex,morey)`. You obviously know how to use points (same parameters as plot) so it's very easy for you to implement, and requires very little extra knowledge on your part.